# How to run logic before lifetime scope is ended in autofac?

Tags: autofac

I know there is the `OnRelease` method when you register a component, there is also `CurrentScopeEnding` event on `ILifetimeScope`, but strangely enough code in both these extension points is executed after you no longer allowed to resolve anything using the lifetime scope in question. You'll get ObjectDisposedException if you try. But I need to! What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is hella old but it's still open so I consider it free game.  Plus I just solved this on my own so I thought I'd answer it since it was high in my google results.  Might help some others out.

Here's what I did to log the lifetimes of `ILifetimeScope` instances:

```
class LifetimeLogger : IStartable
{
    readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public LifetimeLogger(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        //_lifetimeScope = scope;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        initLifetimeScope(_lifetimeScope);
    }

    static void initLifetimeScope(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        //lifetimeScope.
        lifetimeScope.ChildLifetimeScopeBeginning += (sender, args) =>
        {
            log("Begging lifetime scope (tag {0})", args.LifetimeScope.Tag);
            initLifetimeScope(args.LifetimeScope);
        };

        lifetimeScope.CurrentScopeEnding += (sender, args) => log("Ending lifetime scope ({0})", args.LifetimeScope.Tag);
    }
}
```

You could use something like and you'll get to execute logic at the beginning and end of every child lifetime scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit strange to resolve anything from the scope when you current lifetime scope is disposing. Why do you need it? Try to resolve "the thing you need" from root scope.

Comment: That's exactly what I do. It's just that I need "the thing" on saving changes to database. And that only happens when current request is ending - i.e. current lifetime scope is disposing.

Comment: I would recomend you to have your own explicit 'Unit Of Work' (== request scope), but if you insist... Are you sure you resolve TheThing from root context, not from context being disposed? Try to resolve TheThing in advance and then use it in OnRelease...